# Remove root node containing X

Tags: xml, notepad++

```
<manga>
    <manga_mangadb_id>36037</manga_mangadb_id>
    <manga_title><![CDATA["Bungaku Shoujo" to Ue Kawaku Ghost]]></manga_title>
    <manga_volumes>4</manga_volumes>
    <manga_chapters>30</manga_chapters>
    <my_status>Dropped</my_status>
    <my_comments><![CDATA[]]></my_comments>
    <my_tags><![CDATA[Drama, Romance, Shounen, Psychological]]></my_tags>   
</manga>
```

My .XML file contains 14000 lines and the value `<my_status>Dropped</my_status>` appears 125 times. I want to delete the root node and everything in it if it contains `<my_status>Dropped</my_status>` . Is there a way to batch remove it or is doing it by hand the only way?

Comment: Do you really mean delete current node with that *my_status* value? Deleting root node invalidates an XML.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Since I'm not familiar with .XML I was using [link](http://docs.adaptive-vision.com/current/studio/img/manual/XmlDescription.png) as guidance. My .XML file starts with `<myanimelist>` and ends with `</myanimelist>` . [link](https://imgur.com/ieb7Chp) This is a picture of the .XML file in question. Is what I mentioned above not the root node?

Comment: I don't know much about Notepad++, but this sounds like a task for [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT).

Answer (score 0):

Consider running [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files such as removing nodes based on certain conditions. Specifically, run the [identity transform](http://usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) to copy document as is and an empty template to remove needed element conditionally.

You can run XSLT 1.0 scripts in almost any general-purpose language such as C#, Java, Python, PHP, even VBA much like the other special-purpose language (SQL). Additionally, dedicated, standalone tools are available to even run XSLT 2.0 and 3.0. See [tag page here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info).

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->    
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Empty Template to Remove Elements -->   
  <xsl:template match="manga[my_status='Dropped']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below are command line tools available to run XSLT depending on OS.

**Unix** (Mac/Linux) *using [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/), will output new transformed xml*

```
xsltproc -o /path/to/output.xml /path/to/XSLTScript.xsl /path/to/input.xml
```

---

**Windows** *using PowerShell script calling NET's [System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.110).aspx)*

Save below as a .ps1 script

```
param ($xml, $xsl, $output)

if (-not $xml -or -not $xsl -or -not $output) {
    Write-Host "& .\xslt.ps1 [-xml] xml-input [-xsl] xsl-input [-output] transform-output"
    exit;
}

trap [Exception]{
    Write-Host $_.Exception;
}

$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;

$xslt.Load($xsl);
$xslt.Transform($xml, $output);

Write-Host "generated" $output;

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit";
```

**Command line call** *(will output new, transformed XML file)*

```
Powershell.exe -File "C:\Path\To\PowerShell\Script.ps1"^
 "C:\Path\To\Input.xml" "C:\Path\To\XSLTScript.xsl" "C:\Path\To\Ouput.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with an XSLT-processor (version 1.0 and up) using an *empty template* in combination with an *identity template*. Use the following XSLT template to remove all `<manga>` elements which have a `<my_status>` element with the value `Dropped`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>  

  <!-- empty template for all 'mystatus=Dropped` manga elements -->
  <xsl:template match="manga[my_status = 'Dropped']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can apply that i.e. with [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) on Windows and Linux. Or any other XSLT processor you have available.