# Merge all the elements with the same tag if they have same parent

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I am working with the following example xml tree:

```
<group>
   <group_info>
      <Text>
         Text_1
      </Text>
   </group_info>
   <group_info>
      <Text>
         Text_2
      </Text>
   </group_info>
   <group_info>
      <Text>
         Text_3
      </Text>
   </group_info>
</group>
```

I want to merge all the repeated children elements inside `<group>` and group them into one child elements. My desired output:

```
<group>
   <group_info>
      <Text>
         Text_1 Text_2 Text_3
      </Text>
   </group_info>
</group>
```

Without importing any new modules I am using:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
group_list = MY_XML.findall(".//group") # I do this because the actual xml is bigger with several groups 
for elem in group_list:
    string_text = ""
    for child in elem :
        for super_child in child:
            if(super_child.text is not None): #Just in case None value because I cannot use string addition
                string_text = string_text + super_child.text + " "
        elem.remove(child)
    new_child = xml.etree.ElementTree.Element("group_info")
    text_elem = xml.etree.ElementTree.Element("Text")
    text_elem.text = string_text
    new_child.append(text_elem)
    elem.append(new_child)
```

The idea is I loop over all my groups, collect all the text information from `<group_info>` into one string then remove all these elements in my tree and append a new element with the info. This may not be the best way to go at it but I am relatively new. However my output looks like:

```
<group>
   <group_info>
      <Text>
         Text_1
      </Text>
   </group_info>
   <group_info>
      <Text>
         Text_2
      </Text>
   </group_info>
   <group_info>
      <Text>
         Text_3
      </Text>
   </group_info>
<group_info><Text>Text1 Text2 Text3</Text></group_info></group>
```

Technically, the last line is what I need (although it doesn't look pretty) but I have no idea why it's not removing the other unwanted `<group_info>` even when I call `elem.remove(child)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one has come forth to answer, it took me some time but I have answers and pointers if other people run into the same problem.

I started with the initial code you see in the question, which would not remove old elements and left a very ugly last line.

Note that: `MY_XML = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse({PATH_OF_XML})`

1. If you are using xml.etree.ElementTree, you should use remove()
   method to remove a node, but this requires you to have the parent
   node reference. Which I do call `elem.remove(child)` [line 9]
2. So, why are they not being deleted? I found that modifying the
       object that you are iterating affects the iteration. This is not
       entirely unexpected, it is the same if you alter a list while
       iterating over it. I a way I could not store the information and
       remove the elements in one iteration.

I had to split the task:

```
group_list = MY_XML.findall(".//group") # I do this because the actual xml is bigger with several groups
text_list = [] 
for group in group_list:
    string_text = ""
    for child in group :
        for super_child in child:
            if(super_child.text is not None): #Just in case None value because I cannot use string addition
                string_text = string_text + super_child.text + " "
    text_list.append(string_text) #I stored all the info in 1 group as a value in this list because like I stated my overall xml might be bigger with more than 1 group

for group in group_list:
    for elem in group.findall(".//group_info"):
        #loop over all possible <group> and removes all <group_info> inside
        group.remove(elem) 

#And finally to append the information gathered:
for group in group_list:
    Text_elem = ET.Element("Text")
    Text_elem.text = text_list[group_list.index(group)]
    group_info_elem = ET.Element("Kundenhinweis_redigiert")
    group_info_elem.append(Text_elem)
    group.append(Kund_elem)
```

This left me with this very ugly output:

```
<group>
<group_info><Text>Text1 Text2 Text3</Text></group_info></group>
```

which is easily solvable using `xml.dom.minidom` module. I began by defining:

```
def prettify(elem):
    rough_string = xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ")
```

To call the function:

```
root = MY_XML.getroot()
pretty_xml = prettify(root)
#Next line is optional, but sometimes your string contains empty lines or lines with white spaces and/or breaklines
pretty_xml = "\n".join([s for s in pretty_xml.split("\n") if not s.isspace()])
print(pretty_xml)
```

The output will be:

```
<group>
    <group_info>
        <Text>Text1 Text2 Text3</Text>
    </group_info>
</group>
```

Hope this helps other newcomers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files, where you can run the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) by indexing the same node names and grouping their text values. While Python's built-in `xml.ElementTree` does not support XSLT, its third party module, `lxml`, does support XSLT 1.0 scripts. And you can do so without a single `for` loop or having to manually *prettify* outputs.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="group_key" match="group/*" use="name()" />

    <xsl:template match="/group">            
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[generate-id() =
                                   generate-id(key('group_key', name())[1])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="group/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:element name="{name(*)}">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('group_key', name())">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(*)"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>            
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[XSLT Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwB/1) *(demonstrating with two groups)*

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL
doc = et.parse('/path/to/Input.xml')
xsl = et.parse('/path/to/XSLT_Script.xsl')

# CONFIGURE TRANSFORMER
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)    

# RUN TRANSFORMATION
result = transform(doc)

# PRINT RESULT
print(result)  

# SAVE TO FILE
with open('/path/to/Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(result)
```

Comment: I read about it in my search, problem is I work on a company computer and not allowed to install additional python modules. The only two I had were `xml.etree.ElementTree` and `xml.dom.minidom` when I imported 'lxml' I got an ImportError. Oh how I wish. and I have no control over the xml input as I receive it from another department and have to perform changes in python.

Comment: XSLT is an industry language and can be run with [third-party exe](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) or other languages. See [PowerShell and Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50318750/1422451) setup, depending if you use PC or Unix which Python can call at command line with `subprocess`.

Comment: I will give a look into it, might prove to be useful once the tasks get harder. Thank you.